# How can I change the menu icon on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, menu, icons

I'm attempting to customize my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and would like to start by changing the menu icon. I have tried using Chat GPT to generate commands, but when I ran the commands it provided, I encountered multiple errors in the terminal.

Could someone please guide me on the correct procedure to change the menu icon on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B? I would appreciate any specific commands or configuration steps that I need to follow.

Additionally, if there are any troubleshooting tips or common errors to watch out for, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's not called 'Menu icon'. First you need to finf out what distro you are running then find out insstructions for that distro, if they exist at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I apologize for any confusion caused by my use of the term 'Menu icon.' I understand that different Linux distributions may refer to it differently.

To provide more accurate information, I am running Raspberry Pi OS on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. Could you please guide me on how to change the icon in this specific distribution? If there are any specific instructions or resources available, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked, my RPi is running Raspberry OS 10 Buster. You right-click the Menu Icon, click on Menu Settings a window pops up and you can provide a path to an icon, default is 'start-here'